# Facebook PHP SDK 4 - get last 5 posts

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, guzzle

I am trying to get the last five posts.  I have created the following:

```
try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $this->fb->get(
    '/'.$page_id.'/posts',
    $access_token
    );

} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphEdge();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($graphNode);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

How can I limit the output?  For example, instead of 100 records being returned, I only want 5.  I know I need to use 'limit=5' but don't know where in above to place it.

Also, with the above script, I get a massive Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphEdge Object with all sorts of info.  No way to get a smaller more refined object just for posts (eg. title, body, picture, date)?

Comment: Can you try to replace `'/'.$page_id.'/posts'` by `'/'.$page_id.'/posts?fields=id,title,created_time&amp;limit=5'` ? That's the way to only get the fields you want and to use the limit parameter (you'll be able to find all the fields name if you inspect the object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in the comments, you need to add to the url you're calling all these parameters like the *limit* or the fields you want.

So it should be like

```
$response = $this->fb->get(
    '/'.$page_id.'/posts?fields=id,title,created_time&amp;limit=‌​5',
    $access_token
 );
```

If you want to know which fields are available, you can use the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/post/) but this list may not be accurate based on which API version your using. Another way is to inspect the object before specifying the fields.